# Unable to Seed "UnknownAttributeError" when column is single and "NoMethodError" when column is pluralized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

**Question:** How do I seed my postgres db through ActiveRecord when I'm using a many to many relationship with join tables?

I am making my databases and I did it on a separate branch because last time I messed them up somewhere along the line and had to start my project over. I have artists, releases, labels, and tags.

The releases have a many-to-many with the tags. I have

- added `t.belongs_to [tag/release]` to each create_table migration

**create_release_table**:

```rb
class CreateReleases < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :releases do |t|
      t.string :release_type, null: false
      t.string :embed_url
      t.text :title, null: false
      t.integer :original_release_year
      t.belongs_to :artist, null: false
      t.belongs_to :label
      t.belongs_to :tag, null: false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**create_tags_table**:

```rb
class CreateTags < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :tags do |t|
      t.string :tag, null: false
      t.belongs_to :release

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

- made the join table migration

```rb
class CreateReleasesTags < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :releases_tags, :id => false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :release
      t.belongs_to :tag
    end
  end
end
```

- added a  `has_and_belongs_to_many :[tags/ releases]` to my tag and release models

```
  belongs_to :artist
  has_and_belongs_to_many :labels
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

end
```

- ran `bundle exec rake db:migrate && bundle exec rake db:rollback && bundle exec rake db:migrate` which completed without error

I go to run `bundle exec db:seed` though and I get an error regarding tags (and the same thing happens with label but not artist).

- When I put `tag: tag1` it says  `ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'tag' for Release`
- When I change it to `tags: tag1` I get  `NoMethodError: undefined method` each' for #Tag:0x00007f90f7ee1940`

my seed file:

```rb
artist1 = Artist.create(name: "Manilla Road", description: "Heavy metal band from a country that looks like a country", alias: ["Manilla Road", "Other Name"])
tag1 = Tag.create(tag: "heavy-metal")
label1 = Label.create(name: "Polyvinyl", description: "A Label with of Montreal on it")
release1 = Release.create(release_type: "EP", title: "A Cool Tune", description: "Wow. I love this record. So Cool! Here is its history!", artist: artist1, original_release_year: 1997, tag: tag1, label: label1)
```

my full schema:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_08_01_134359) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "artists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.text "description"
    t.text "alias", default: [], array: true
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "artists_releases", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "artist_id"
    t.bigint "release_id"
    t.index ["artist_id"], name: "index_artists_releases_on_artist_id"
    t.index ["release_id"], name: "index_artists_releases_on_release_id"
  end

  create_table "labels", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.text "description"
    t.bigint "release_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["release_id"], name: "index_labels_on_release_id"
  end

  create_table "labels_releases", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "label_id"
    t.bigint "release_id"
    t.index ["label_id"], name: "index_labels_releases_on_label_id"
    t.index ["release_id"], name: "index_labels_releases_on_release_id"
  end

  create_table "releases", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "release_type", null: false
    t.string "embed_url"
    t.text "title", null: false
    t.integer "original_release_year"
    t.bigint "artist_id", null: false
    t.bigint "label_id"
    t.bigint "tag_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.text "description"
    t.index ["artist_id"], name: "index_releases_on_artist_id"
    t.index ["label_id"], name: "index_releases_on_label_id"
    t.index ["tag_id"], name: "index_releases_on_tag_id"
  end

  create_table "releases_tags", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "release_id"
    t.bigint "tag_id"
    t.index ["release_id"], name: "index_releases_tags_on_release_id"
    t.index ["tag_id"], name: "index_releases_tags_on_tag_id"
  end

  create_table "tags", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "tag"
    t.bigint "release_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["release_id"], name: "index_tags_on_release_id"
  end

end
```

Comment: "When I change it to `tags: tag1` I get NoMethodError: undefined method each' for #Tag:0x00007f90f7ee1940" - This error message looks quite self-explanatory - you'e using scalar value in the context where a collection is expected. Did you try `tags: [tag1]`?

Comment: this solved it! Thank you!!